# The term for a person who provides a reference for someone for a job

Tags: terminology

When writing a CV or something similar, one often provides contact information to a person, who may be contacted for references about oneself (e.g. about work attitude or other qualifications).

What is the person, who provides the reference or testimonial, called?

*edit:* I did come by the term *referee*, but that does not feel right as I associate that more with sports.

Comment: Have you searched to see if *other* people frequently use the term 'referee' in that context?

Comment: See also: [What does 'reference' mean in a CV?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64519/14073)

Comment: If referring is the verb, a Referee is the one receiving the referring and a Referrer is the one who would be doing the referring.  I don't understand the use of Referee for one who gives a reference at all.

Comment: @MrWonderful - if A tells B that to find some information they need to talk to C, this action is a reference.  A is the active party, and is therefore the *referrer*.  B is the subject and therefore the *referand* (they have been *referred to C*).  The reference given by A is a *reference to C* and C is therefore the *referee*.  This is the original meaning of the word "reference" (1589 is the first citation in OED). The fact that in this specific case the information that C provides to B is generally called a reference is a modern corruption of the meaning (earliest citation 1895).

Comment: @Jules Thank you so very much for that elucidating reply!   I feel enriched (as should the OP!)

Comment: Perhaps the problem here is with the assumption that there IS a commonly-used English word.  At least in my own experience, it's always a phrase like "the person who provided the reference".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The person is your ***reference***.  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/reference):

> A reference is a person who gives you a reference, for example when
>   you are applying for a job.

Example, made up:

> Student to Professor:  I'm applying to Brown for grad school. Will you
>   be one of my references?

[Clarification:  As the OP mentioned, a reference is also (see above link):

> A reference is a letter that is written by someone who knows you and
>   which describes your character and abilities. When you apply for a
>   job, an employer might ask for references]

Comment: Ooh, a circular reference. :P

Comment: @Lawrence More of a spiral.

Comment: Ha! The feelings of weighty references aside, you've now gone the whole hog :) . You can make reference to an attached reference from your reference to satisfy the interviewer's request for references.

Comment: @Lawrence `public Reference Reference { get { return this.Reference; } }`

Comment: @Lawrence And if you are mentioning a specific interviewer in an e-mail, you can make reference to an attached reference from your reference to satisfy the referenced interviewer's request for references.

Comment: Oh dear, spirals indeed. :P

Answer (score 9):

I grew up in the USA, and did some job-seeking in New Zealand.

The term "**referee**" is the typical **New Zealand** term that I heard, from sites providing locally-oriented resume advice, as well as from some colleagues.

In **American English** (from California, at least), "**reference**" is what I would expect. Indeed, "referee" sounded strange to my ear when I first heard it in NZ!

Comment: It seems bizarre to me that they'd use "referee," since you would expect it to work like "employee" or "payee" and refer to the party receiving.  Not saying you're wrong; just totally bizarre to me.

Comment: I'm equally perplexed by local variants like "kerb" (curb, side-of-road-thing) or "school leaver" (recent graduate). There seem to be a handful of local dialectal quirks like that which aren't considered iconic, so they're not things that you get told specifically to adjust to (unlike the "fush 'n chups" pronunciation).

Comment: I'm a New Zealander, and I came here expecting the top answer to say that the correct term was "referee"... TIL that we're even weirder than I thought.

Comment: In BrE as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think in England people say *referee*. As an American, I say *reference*.

Comment: Please consider including references (pun intended) to make this into a better answer.

Comment: I'm English and have commonly heard *referee,* although *reference* is gaining traction. Perhaps it's an age thing.

Comment: I'm English also and have mainly heard reference used, I have seen referee a couple of times on documents and forms though.

Comment: I hear it from friends and I'm a dinosaur (almost *40* you damn kids) so yeah maybe it's an age thing. However, there are tons of results when you google **english referee reference**; here's the first http://www.jobs.ac.uk/careers-advice/cv-templates/1536/how-to-choose-your-referees

Comment: In Australia, *referee* is also fairly common but *reference* also occurs - not just recently; I heard it decades ago - and would be understood more broadly than it's used (as would *referer*)

Comment: My experience in England is that "Referee" is usually used to refer to the people/person specifically - and "References" is used more generically and interchangeably for the documents/data and the people in the whole. eg "Please could you provide references" in general,  "Your Referee, [name] had good things to say about you" in particular.

Answer (score 3):

How about *referrer*? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referrer) describes it as:

> A person who refers another.

Comment: Yeah, but it sounds extremely strange to start talking about referrers, or referents, in this context.

Answer (score 3):

*Reference* can be used to refer to both the person providing a testimonial and the testimonial provided by that person.

*Referrer* only works if the person is involved by introducing you to a company as a candidate for a position.